# Add Grid to ItemsPanelTemplate of an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, itemscontrol

I want to add a `Grid` as `ItemPanelTemplate` of an `ItemsControl` in WPF.

I know that there are lots of similar questions. But all of them I have seen so far are talking about dynamically adding rows and columns and they haven't covered it in a good way (in my point of view).

So the thing I want might be the simplest form But I don't know how to do it.

Of course I know that it is not going to work. But it's just for the sake of showing my idea.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ArticleName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ArticleTradeName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                .
                .
                .
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
  ----------------------------------------
  | #1 name     |  #1 trade name         |
  ---------------------------------------
  | GridView                             |
  |     Row1                             |
  |    Row2                              |
  |    .                                 |
  |    .                                 |
  |     RowN                             |  
  ----------------------------------------
  | #2 name     |  #2 trade name         |
  ----------------------------------------
  | GridView                             |
  |    Row1                              |
  |    Row2                              |
  |    .                                 |
  |    .                                 |
  |     RowN                             | 
  ----------------------------------------
  ...
```

Comment: On a second look, it seems like you're misunderstanding `ItemsPanelTemplate` (why not just put the grid inside `DataTemplate`?)  In any case, it's not clear what kind of layout you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You know I have a list which I want to draw each Item in a way that I have two different TextBox which are bound and a GridView underneath them which it is bound as well.

Comment: I'm not close to understanding you.  Can you mock up a layout, like the example in my edit to your question?

Comment: The thing I want is exactly the same layout as you drew. but instead of '???' I want a gridView which I Used a ListView Instead

Comment: Ok, but what's in the grid view / list view?

Comment: I think you are right. I am misundrstood about ItemsPanelTemplate. I thing I don't know its usage completely. I think I can use just ItemTemplate as you've just already said

Comment: In GridView I have a list of other Items. Actually I have a list of "Articles" in which I have a nested list called "Samples" that I want to show inside the GridView

Comment: Got it ... I added another answer below.  Just bind the ListView's ItemsSource to your nested list "Samples".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to change the `ItemsPanel` from its default (StackPanel).  Simply put the `Grid` inside the ItemTemplate itself.  Like this:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ArticleName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ArticleTradeName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Samples}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            .
                            .
                            .
                        <GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Oh I think now I understand what is the usage of ItemPanelTempate. its default is StackPanle?! and If I want to change the way Items are arranging I have to change its PanelTemplate. I have missed this important point. Thank you very much for your kindness.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh See also [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx). If you set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on the `ItemsControl` and add `SharedSizeGroup`s to your item template's column definitions, all the columns will line up.